# SimpleHTTPServer launched as a thread: does not daemonize

Tags: python, httpserver

I would like to launch a `SimpleHTTPServer` in a separate thread, while doing something else (here, `time.sleep(100)`) in the main one. Here is a simplified sample of my code:

```
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer

server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
print 'OK UNTIL NOW'
thread = threading.Thread(target = server.serve_forever())
print 'STUCK HERE'
thread.setdaemon = True
try:
    thread.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.shutdown()
    sys.exit(0)

print 'OK'

time.sleep(120)
```

However, the thread remains "blocking", i.e. is not launched as a daemon and the interpreter does not reach the `print 'OK'`. It does not neither reach the `STUCK HERE`.

I have though that the thread would only be initialized when calling `threading.Thread(...)` and that the main thread would still go further until it found the `thread.start` instruction to launch it.

Is there any better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: thread = threading.Thread(target = server.serve_forever)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change this:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target = server.serve_forever())
```

To be this:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target = server.serve_forever)
```

And change this:

```
thread.setdaemon = True
```

To be this:

```
thread.daemon = True
```

Comment: I bet this was a typo. thread.setDaemon(True) is also possible.

Answer (score 3):

Try `thread = threading.Thread(target = server.serve_forever)`, i.e. without the call.

The problem with your version is that serve_forever() is called on parsing the line where the thread is created. Thus, you never get to the next line.

The argument type must be callable, which will be called on thread start, so
you need to pass name, `server.serve_forever` instead of trying to pass result of executing this function.