# Python 2 Problems running HTTP and HTTPS server in different threads

Tags: python-2.7

I run a stoppable **http** server for testing on localhost in python2.7 (ubuntu 16.04).
Additionally, I'd like to have the **https** server as well, so I tried the following code

```
try:
  start_new_thread(httpd.serve_forever())
  start_new_thread(httpsd.serve_forever())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print("\nClosing the service...")
```

*httpd* and *httpsd* are of type *BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer* and listen on 3000 (http) and 3001 (https). For *https* a self signed certificate is used.
**Each server runs properly** if tested alone, but with the code above, **only the first started server thread** (in our case *httpd*) runs in 'multithreaded' mode and delivers data. The server in the second thread **simply does not respond** to any request...

Can anybody please tell me, what's wrong with the snippet above?
Or otherwise show me a solution based on the approach above?
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Got it; the answer to my problem according to [this SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364083/simplehttpserver-launched-as-a-thread-does-not-daemonize) is: that instead of

```
try:
  start_new_thread(httpd.serve_forever())
  start_new_thread(httpsd.serve_forever())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
```

I have to use true non-blocking function pointer

```
thread1 = Thread(target = httpd.serve_forever) # Without ()
thread2 = Thread(target = httpsd.serve_forever) # Without ()
try:
  thread1.start()
  thread2.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Ridiculous